# Storing data from System.out.print(output)

Tags: java, arrays

First of all, I am sorry if the question was vague or unclear.

I am trying to store System.out.print(output) into sort of like an array.

For example

I have a global variable call `name = "Mike"`.

the input was `str = "Hello";`

`System.out.println(str + name);`

I want to store that output in the somewhere which I don't know.

Then another input `str1 = "Bye"`

`System.out.println(str1 + name);`

I want to store this one too.

When I want to view them. 
The result should be

```
Hello Mike.

Bye Mike.
```

They are supposed to print at the same time. NOT one by one.

FYI, the store variable cannot be global.The reason to store is because I need an input from the user (at most two input) and when I call view() method it should print out

```
Hello Mike.

Bye Mike.
```

What should I do?
Should I use loop?
If my way of thinking was terrible, sorry in advance.

Can you give me better way?
Can someone explain to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i =0;i<2;i++){
    String a = sc.nextLine();
    li.add(a + " Mike");
}
//System.out.println(li); 
for(int j=0;j<li.size();j++) {
          System.out.println(li.get(j));
      }
```

instead of 2 read an integer uing scanner and replace 2 with n

Comment: it's printing out [hello Mike, bye Mike]. How can I make it separate line.

Comment: I edited the code just look into it.replaced System.out.println(li);  with some code.

Comment: Thank you so much, Saragada.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out` stream is a `PrintStream` that can be re-set.

This snippet more or less does that for you.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    private final List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListPrintStream() {
        super(System.out);

    }

    public void print(final String x) {
        super.print(x);
        output.add(x);
    }

    // override other print methods for other types

    public List<String> getOutput() {
        return output;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ListPrintStream out = new ListPrintStream();
        System.setOut(out);

        System.out.println("some line");
        System.out.println("some other line");

        final List<String> list = out.getOutput();
        for (final String l : list) System.err.println(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's printing out [some line, some other line]. How can I make it separate line.

Comment: `getOutput()` returns a `List<String>`. Just iterate over that list.